# Fitting MultinomialNB on multiple columns of data

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

Given a table of data containing 100 rows, such as:

```
Place    | Text             | Value | Text_Two
europe   | some random text | 3.2   | some more random text
america  | the usa          | 4.1   | the white house
...
```

I am trying to classify with the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
mnb = MultinomialNB()
tf = TfidfVectorizer()

df.loc[df['Place'] == 'europe','Place'] = 0
df.loc[df['Place'] == 'america','Place'] = 1

X = df[['Text', 'Value', 'Text_Two']]
y = df['Place']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25)
X_train_tf = tf.fit_transform(X_train)

mnb.fit(X_train_tf, y_train)
```

The above produces the following error:

> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of
>   samples: [3, 100]

So from what I understand it's only seeing the categories that were set with `X = df[['Text', 'Value', 'Text_Two']]`, not the data within those categories.

The code above works if I only specify X for one category, such as:
    X = df['Text']

Is it possible to fit the MultinomialNB on multiple categories of data?

Answer (score 0):

I rather combine columns Text and Text_Two as one column then construct the classifier from there. MultinomialNB works only for one classifier. Below is the code that combines columns Text and Text_Two into one.

You might be interested on multi-class or multi-label classification but it refers to the target variables (Y) rather than the dependent variables (X).
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html. Hope it helps.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=0, sep='|')
df.columns = [x.strip() for x in df.columns]

mnb = MultinomialNB()
tf = TfidfVectorizer()

#df.loc[df['Place'] == 'europe','Place'] = 0
#df.loc[df['Place'] == 'america','Place'] = 1
#X = df[['Text', 'Value', 'Text_Two']]
X = df.Text + df.Text_Two
y = df['Place']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25)
pipe = make_pipeline(TfidfVectorizer(), MultinomialNB())
pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
pipe.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: Thats not due to `MultinomialNB`, but `TfidfVectorizer`. `TfidfVectorizer` only works on a single column of text which will be converted to a 2-d array according to the terms found.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with MultinomialNB. It can handle multiple columns fine. The problem is TfidfVectorizer.

TfidfVectorizer only works on a an iterable of single dimension (single column of your dataframe) and will not do any kind of check on the shape or type of the input data.

It will [only do this](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f0ab589f/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L790):

```
for doc in raw_documents:
...
...
```

When you pass a dataframe to it (be it a single column or multiple columns), `for doc in raw_documents:`, on a dataframe will only output the column names and not actual data. The data you pass in `X` has three columns, so only those columns are used as documents, and hence the error

`ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [3, 100]`

because your `y` will have 100 length, and your X (even though it has length 100, but due to tfidfvectorizer it will only now have 3 length).

So to solve this, you have two options:

1) You need to do individual tf-idf vectorization for each text column (`Text`, `Text_Two`) and then combine the resultant matrices to form the feature matrix to be used with MultinomialNB.

2) You can combine the two text columns into a single column as @âńōŋŷxmoůŜ has suggested and then do tf-idf on that single column.

Both options will result in different feature vectors, so you need to first understand what each one does and choose what you want.